# Firebase: How to set token expiry?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

Is there a way to set token expiry for Firebase auth? I was looking at the console and SDK docs and there seem to be no way?

Answer (score 0):

Tokens expire after one hour and will be automatically refreshed by the SDK after that.  You have no control over the expiration time, as that's controlled by the service, which is not configurable at all (other than enabling and disabling individual providers).